# Sprite Kit iOS 7 - how to add a shadow to a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have a `SKSpriteNode` containing other `SKSpriteNodes`. How can I create a copy of this `SKSpriteNode` where all the pixels are black?

Once I have this shadow `SKSpriteNode` I will then flip it upside down and use it as a shadow.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a shadow using the same image like this :

```
SKSpriteNode *shadow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"YourImageName"];

shadow.blendMode = SKBlendModeAlpha;
shadow.colorBlendFactor = 1;
shadow.color = [SKColor blackColor];
shadow.alpha = .25;  // make shadow partly transparent
```

Then just position it however you like based on desired light direction. Alpha isn't needed if you want it to be solid black.

Comment: thanks this very nearly works. The shadow is still in colour though

Comment: I needed to go through all children nodes too.